# Get the height of a whole page in pixel

Tags: javascript, html, height

For some decoration, I need to insert an upper margin at the beginning of the document which represent 34% of the whole height of the page (margin included).
My page < body> start like this:

```
    <body bgcolor="#dedede" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
        <tbody>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#dedede">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="premier-tableau" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                        <thead>
                                <tr height="500" /> <!-- I need to use this line as a margin -->
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="35" />
                                <td width="530">
                                    <font color="#5e5e5e" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" style="font-size: 12px;">
```

This is for using in e-mails.

Of course it is possible to calculate manually the number of pixel, and add the static result to the < tr> tag. But, It is part of a semi-automated process, and I would like to avoid that.
Also note that the destination SMTP server may have a strict policy and refuse attachments. So, I don't see how to use externals libraries (such as JQuery). As a modern ecmascript is available, I would like to avoid using them...

Any embeddable solutions (css;javascript;svg ...) are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the viewports Units which have been designed for that. Few browser support it actually, but using `height="34vh"` will be the right way to proceed in some years.

It will take some years for clients to comply with the standard. An actual way to proceed now, is to compute the size (in px) manually each time the document is edited.

Comment: I don't think that's a very good answer to your own problem, as you are aware it is barely supported. Further note that some styles that are currently supported in browsers also don't work in emails.

Comment: @m59 : You were right for javascript too many imap client disable JavaScript. In 6/9 years, this will be the right solution, since the current is : I CAN'T!

Answer (score 3):

`document.body.parentNode.offsetHeight` but - javascript isn't going to run in emails :) I therefore think that you need to do this manually.

Comment: I don't unserstand what document.body.parentNode.offsetHeight does... could you explain it. For javascript.... wrong! Most of my recipient use Thunderbird (which use the same gecko engine in firefox) or a webmail... I have already some parts in the head section and it is working.

Comment: Most email services don't allow javascript. Google hardly allows html, lol. Anyway, do what you want.

`document.body` just selects the body. `parentNode` of the body is the `html` tag, which may have additional height. I prefer to select it just to be sure, since you said you wanted the full height of the whole page. `offsetHeight` should be the total height of the element, including margins/padding. I also feel it's relevant to mention that some email services will also strip out the `html` tag and even the `body` tag! @user2284570

Comment: I have ever seen HTML5/css3 working in gmail webmail... Thunderbird allow even HTML5 youtube video with iframes... the website consulted though iframes receive a firefox user-agent :)

Comment: Sorry, but i steel don't understand whit offsetHeight. Actually it give 54(viewed HTML debugger) with my page which contain more than 20 lines...

Comment: @user2284570 are you using it after the whole page is rendered?

Comment: Yes, after the the whole page rendred... (54 and without any margin (the document start at the top)) however, offsetWidth give 1680 which is the width of my screen...

Comment: @user2284570 I don't know what to tell you...check this out - it does work. http://jsbin.com/APIMUrI/1/edit  Show me exactly what you're doing and maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: Ok, No problem In my browser. Of course, Unless you don't send it by mail I can't tell... (I'll try myself later)

Answer (score 0):

since you have no margins on the body, a simple height should do it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].height
```

Comment: It won't include the number of pixel token by the margin. Here the size of the ratio I need is final_body= margin 34% and main 66%. It would give the height of the document and apply the margin after which wouldn't be what I want.